# Laravel does not accept new database user in the .env file

Tags: mysql, laravel, laradock

I'm setting up my laravel dev environment using a different username. I don't want to use the root user to access my database.

By the way, I'm using Laradock. So I'm not using the normal homestead credentials.

If I use the new user, and run `php artisan migrate`, it keeps giving me the following error:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'newuser'@'172.25.0.4' (using password: YES)")
>
> PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=db_name", "db_user", "db_password!", [])

I have done the following steps already:

1. Restarted the server (docker-compose down, then up, then restarted docker)
2. `php artisan config:clear`
3. `php artisan cache:clear`
4. `php artisan config:cache`

TAKE NOTE:
It only throws this error if I'm using the new user but it works totally fine with the root user. The new user has GRANT ALL privilege as well.

My `.env` file contains:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
```

I expect to be able to run php artisan migrate using the new user credentials instead of the default root user.

Comment: change the host to localhost

Comment: is your database remote or localhost?

Comment: is there any chance your user host is properly define? "%" <--all not advisable though

Comment: Thank you @PayamKhaninejad. Changing the db_host from mysql to localhost fixed it!

Comment: @Franz Happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set correct value for DB_HOST.
If Your DB in local network, then you can set DB_HOST=localhost, or you may use external IP addres, for example DB_HOST=172.25.0.4

After it run

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thank you @Максим Абдалов, it fixed the issue!